# Append table column value with text when id's match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where i need to append some text after a data change. The first column in the table row holds the ID which I check is equal to the variable id and then append the word 'Updated!' to the id in the table cell. I have the following code but from what I have tested out it doesnt seem to get the equality right between the table row id and the variable id values. Can someone point me in the right direction for this to work please?

```
var id =  $('#id').val();

        $("td:first-child").each(function() {
            if ($(this).text() == id){
                $('<p>Updated!</p>').appendTo('$(this).text()');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Provide a working sample (which includes also your html), and not just your js code.

Comment: Try to log the types of the *table row id* and the *variable id* (ex. `typeof $(this).text()`). If they have different types, try to make the types of your two variables equal.

Comment: @Matthias, both are returning string types when using typeof

Comment: @JeepersCreepers - Log both values, then you'll know if the comparison is the problem as you think.

Comment: Yep found it, needed to trim() the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using `appendTo` (http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) properly. Please check the docs. When you append some element, you must append it to another element (not text). Also, you have quotes around the wrong piece `$(this).text()`, so that's a string and we're looking for an element. Try changing it to this:

```
var id =  $('#id').val();

$("td:first-child").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == id){
        $('<p>Updated!</p>').appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

Comment: I have amended my code so that the appendto function should now work.

Answer (score 0):

Read more about **appendTo()** function. It should look like that:

```
$('<p>Updated!</p>').appendTo($(this));
```

It basically appends text or html content to and element, not to a string (which you provided).

---

**appendTo()** on jQuery API Dosc: http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Answer (score 0):

I found what the issue was with the equality between the 2 variables. I needed to trim() the values.